# I can't push my app to heroku because of trying to install canvas

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, canvas, discord.js

When I try pushing to heroku, I get this error.
The thing is, I was trying to install canvas on heroku, but now I can't get rid of this error.
I already tried `npm uninstall canvas` but somehow it still appears there.
I also tried removing some modules like node-gyp but they still appear there, though they aren't on my package.json.

```
remote:        > canvas@2.6.1 install /tmp/build_4576c7a5/node_modules/canvas
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        Package pangocairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
remote:        Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pangocairo.pc'
remote:        to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
remote:        No package 'pangocairo' found
remote:        gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pangocairo --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
remote:        gyp ERR! configure error
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_4576c7a5/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:379:20)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1083-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_4576c7a5/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_4576c7a5/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/tmp/build_4576c7a5/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/tmp/build_4576c7a5/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v88"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_4576c7a5/node_modules/canvas
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v15.7.0
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/tmp/build_4576c7a5/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_4576c7a5/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_4576c7a5/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/tmp/build_4576c7a5/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_4576c7a5/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:379:20)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1069:16)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:300:5)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1083-aws
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_4576c7a5/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_4576c7a5/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_4576c7a5/node_modules/canvas
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.7.0
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
remote:        Failed to execute '/tmp/build_4576c7a5/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_4576c7a5/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_4576c7a5/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/tmp/build_4576c7a5/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.6.1 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.5ucmj/_logs/2021-02-01T18_37_13_927Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 501cbf059ab6b2d73a0c9f836a8a20a7c6d492f0
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 501cbf059ab6b2d73a0c9f836a8a20a7c6d492f0
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to artificial-friend.
remote:
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
      "name": "program",
      "version": "0.3.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "main.js",
      "author": "BrunoRM",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node main.js"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": "15.x",
        "npm": "^6.14.9"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@discordjs/opus": "^0.3.3",
        "@k3rn31p4nic/google-translate-api": "^1.1.1",
        "ascii-table": "0.0.9",
        "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
        "cairo": "0.1.0-alpha.3",
        "country-timezone": "^1.0.8",
        "currency-converter-lt": "^1.0.0",
        "decode-encode-binary": "^1.0.3",
        "discord-player": "^3.0.3",
        "discord.js": "^12.5.1",
        "distube": "^2.8.6",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "easymaty": "^1.0.22",
        "espchatbotapi": "^1.4.2",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "ffmpeg": "0.0.4",
        "ffmpeg-static": "^4.2.7",
        "figlet": "^1.5.0",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "gifify": "^2.4.3",
        "google-images": "^2.1.0",
        "google-it": "^1.5.4",
        "gtk": "0.0.1",
        "html-entities": "^2.0.2",
        "http": "0.0.0",
        "image-search-google": "^1.3.0",
        "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
        "mathjs": "^8.0.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
        "mongoose": "^5.10.17",
        "myscrapper": "^0.1.5",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
        "node-osu": "^2.2.0",
        "node.js": "0.0.1-security",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
        "opusscript": "^0.0.7",
        "pkg-config": "^1.1.1",
        "request": "^2.88.2",
        "simple-get": "^4.0.0",
        "string-progressbar": "^1.0.1",
        "string-similarity": "^4.0.3",
        "tineye-api": "^1.1.4",
        "tnai": "^1.0.5",
        "virustotal-api": "^1.1.3",
        "youtube-dl": "^3.0.2",
        "ytdl": "^1.4.1",
        "ytdl-core": "^4.4.4",
        "ytdl-core-discord": "^1.2.5"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`? How do you push your repo to Heroku?

Comment: i got that same error a few weeks ago. I still haven't solved it... :/

Comment: i added my package.json to the post